# Reference in C++ classes

Tags: c++, qt, reference

I'm new to programming. I can not understand how to make a reference to the methods of another class.

I have several files and classes:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtCore/QtGlobal>
#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Valve;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    void openValve(int id);
    void closeValve(int id);


private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Settings *settings;
    Valve *valve;
};

class A {
...
private:
void start();
}
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint);
    this->setFixedSize(this->geometry().width(),this->geometry().height()); 

    //класс для 7 клапанов
    valve = new Valve(7);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete settings;
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::valveSwitch(int id)   
{
    if (valve->getState(id))
        closeValve(id);
    else
        openValve(id);
}

void MainWindow::openValve(int id)
{
    QString str = "Valve №" + QString::number(id);
    valveButton[id-1]->setEnabled(false);
    if (valve->open(id)) {
        valveButton[id-1]->setEnabled(true);
        //valveButton[id-1]->setPalette(QPalette(Qt::green));
        //valveButton[id-1]->setStyleSheet(VALVE_OPEN_COLOR);
        QString style = QString(DEFAULT_STYLE_BUTTON) + QString(DEFAULT_BACKGROUND_BUTTON);
        valveButton[id-1]->setStyleSheet(style);
        ui->mainLabel->setText(str + " open! :)");
    }
    else {
        valveButton[id-1]->setEnabled(true);
        ui->mainLabel->setText("Cant open " + str);
        remoteDisconnect();
    }
}
void MainWindow::closeValve(int id)
{
    QString str = "Valve №" + QString::number(id);
    valveButton[id-1]->setEnabled(false);
    if (valve->close(id)) {
        valveButton[id-1]->setEnabled(true);
        //valveButton[id-1]->setPalette(style()->standardPalette());
        valveButton[id-1]->setStyleSheet("");
        ui->mainLabel->setText(str + " close! :)");
    }
    else {
        valveButton[id-1]->setEnabled(true);
        ui->mainLabel->setText("Cant close " + str);
        remoteDisconnect();
    }
}
A::A
{
}
A::~A
{
}
void A::start()
{
//MainWindow::openValve(2);
//valve.open(3);
}
```

How do I access MainWindow class methods openValve/closeValve from class A?
Or how can I access an instance *valve* of a class **Valve** of MainWindow's constructor from class A?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a `MainWindow` object into the `A::start` method:

```
class A {
...
private:
    void start(MainWindow & w);
}

void A::start(MainWindow & w) {
    w._MainWindow_method_name_here_();
}
```

Or you should declare a static method in `MainWindow` class:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    static void aStaticMethod();
};

void MainWindow::aStaticMethod() {
    ...
}

void A::start() {
    MainWindow::aStaticMethod();
}
```

To access protected/private methods of `MainWindow` you should declare the `A` class as a friend of `MainWindow`:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    friend class A;
    ...
};
```

**Update**

> I create a new class for it to work in a separate thread, and call its methods from the main class (by clicking on the button). Accordingly, I need class A to open / close valves, etc.

The "true Qt way" is to use [signals & slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) mechanism.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

// Transform open/closeValve methods into slots
// (a method that can be assigned as an event handler)
//
public slots:
    void openValve(int id);
    void closeValve(int id);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Settings *settings;
    Valve *valve;
};


// This class should be a descendant of QObject
//
class A : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

// Transform this method to a slot, so it can be called
// as regular method, or can be assigned as an event handler,
// for instance, as QPushButton::click handler.
//
public slots:
    void start();

// Add signals
//
signals:
    void openValveSignal(int id);
    void closeValveSignal(int id);
}

void A::start()
{
    // do something and then emit the signal to open valve,
    // MainWindow::openValve(2) will be called
    emit openValveSignal(2);
    ...
    // do something and then emit the signal to close valve,
    // MainWindow::closeValve(3) will be called
    emit closeValveSignal(3);
}


// connects A signals with MainWindow slots,
// so when you `emit A::***Signal()` then corresponding
// `MainWindow::***` method will be called
//
void initialize(MainWindow * pWnd, A * pA)
{
    QObject::connect(pA, &A::openValveSignal, pWnd, &MainWindow::openValve);
    QObject::connect(pA, &A::closeValveSignal, pWnd, &MainWindow::closeValve);
}
```

You can call `a->start()` method from `MainWindow` methods as usual. Or you can connect button `clicked` signal with `A::start` method, for instance:

```
void initialize(MainWindow * pWnd, QAbstractButton * pBtn, A * pA)
{
    // C++11 lambda function is used here because A::start has no arguments
    QObject::connect(pBtn, &QAbstractButton::clicked, [pA](){ pA->start(); });

    QObject::connect(pA, &A::openValveSignal, pWnd, &MainWindow::openValve);
    QObject::connect(pA, &A::closeValveSignal, pWnd, &MainWindow::closeValve);
}
```

so when you click a button then `A::start` method will be called automatically. And then `MainWindow::open/closeValve` methods will be called from `A::start` method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I create a new class for it to work in a separate thread, and call its methods from the main class (by clicking on the button). Accordingly, I need class A to open / close valves, etc. And it was displayed on GUI.
How I can call "start" method?
And why do we need a static method in this case?

Comment: Static method is just an example of calling `MainWindow` methods from `A`. Actually, you may do not need static methods at all.

Comment: I've updated the answer. See how you can use Qt Signals & Slots mechanism to call class `A` methods (and `mainWindow`).

Comment: A great solution with the use of the mechanism of signals and slots! It never entered my head.

So, how can I interact directly with the GUI of the main window from class A? For example, in a separate thread, the method "start" of the class A is executed, and I need to constantly change the value of the bar progress, inscriptions, etc. There must be some way out ... I would also like to have access to the instance "valve" (in fact there are more of them: valves, sensors, etc.), and I can not understand how to implement it.

Comment: Class A is just one of the modes of operation. I could implement the mainwindow class method, but it all depends on putting them in a separate thread. Accordingly, I need to create separate classes for these modes.

Comment: For progress you can use multiple `void progressChanged(data...)` signals in all classes that perform long tasks and a single slot `updateProgress(data..)` in the `MainWindow` class. You can pass any data in signals/slots, for instance `public slots: void processValve(Valve *v);` but you should use synchronization objects (like mutex) inside `Valve` to protect it from modifying by threads simultaneously.

Comment: I do not think very well. Is the function "initialize" in the file "mainwindow.cpp", right? Where and how do I call it?

Comment: It depends where you perform the init of `MainWindow` and `A`. I would say the good place for it in the `MainWindow` constructor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142752/discussion-between-marat-gareev-and-dmitry-sokolov).

Answer (score 1):

```
//MainWindow::openValve(2);
//valve.open(3);
```

At very first:

openValve is not static, so you need an instance of MainWindow to be able to call it:

```
MainWindow* mw_ex0;
// alternatively, if more appropriate:
MainWindow& mw_ex1;

mw_ex0->openValve(2);
mw_ex1.openValve(2);
```

The MainWindow instance could be a parameter of your function `start` or a member variable of class `A` – depending on your concrete needs.

Same applies if you want to access the valve member (valve is a pointer, so you need operator->): `mw_ex0->valve->open(3);` or `mw_ex1.valve->open(3);`).

However, you need to grant class A access to those currently private members; three options:

1. Make A a friend class of MainWindow - this allows A to access MainWindow's private members (might apply for Valve class, too, if `open` is not public).
2. Make the appropriate functions public (MainWindow::openValve and Valve::open); to access the valve member of MainWindow, too, you *could* make it public, too, but it is in general not recommendable to make the internals of a class publicly available to the outside world - someone might simply change your valve member to something else - and your program is broken... So rather provide a simple getter for.
3. Make A an inner class of MainWindow. Then it gets access to its outer class members implicitly (depending on the requirements for class A, this might not be suitable – up to you to decide...).

*Sidenotes:*

- In your constructor, you do not initialise the `settings` member.
- You do not clean up the valve member in your destructor (potential memory leak).

To avoid having to clean up, you could to incorporate valve directly in your class - this is not always suitable, but might be a good option here (up to you to decide, just showing the alternative):

```
class MainWindow
{
    Valve valve;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow()
    : valve(7) // calls constructor directly
{ }
```

Be aware that you now do use operator. to access the valve's members (`mw_ex0->valve.open(3);`). Advantage is that Valve will no be automatically cleaned up together with MainWindow. Alternatively, a `std::unique_ptr` could be used to hold the pointer to your Valve instance, then you get automatic cleanup, too.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer!
 Why do we need a static method in this case?
I create a new class A for it to work in a separate thread, and call its methods from the main class (by clicking on the button). Accordingly, I need class A to open / close valves, etc. And it was displayed on GUI.

1. I actually announced the instance settings, the files are very large and I reduced them for easy reading.

2. I do not know how to work with memory leaks. Not enough experience, but thanks for the instruction! :)

Comment: I need create an instance of MainWindow in the class A constructor? But I already created in a file main.cpp (Can I create a second time?)

Comment: @MaratGareev No. You need to have your instance of MainWindow available within the start function. You now have two options: 1. pass in the instance as parameter into your start function - either as a pointer or as a reference - but not as copy!

Comment: @MaratGareev 2. If you construct your class A *after* the MainWindow *and* the MainWindow will exist over all the livetime of A, you *can* pass the instance to A's constructor instead - again as pointer or reference - and you store it inside A only as pointer or reference (again: not a copy!). This approach is more dangerous, you need to guarantee above mentioned conditions! But it spares you to pass the parameter to start at possibly multiple different locations where sometimes only A is directly available, but not the MainWindow...

Answer (score 0):

Declare `openValve` as public method and `valve` as public object (`open` must be public too)

Then use as:

```
MainWindow mainWindow;

mainWindow.openValve(2);
mainWindow.valve.open(3);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer! That is, you suggest I create two instances of the MainWindow class (in main.cpp and in class A)?